# d3 chart width doesnt display the label on the x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bV5GE/) that the chart has a width of 500.

```
var w = 500;
var h = 500;
```

I'm trying to insert a lot of data into `d3` chart so I need for that width larger than 500  I have this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/d0ogL90d/) with

```
var w = 500000;
var h = 500;
```

it works with a nice scroller but I cant see the x axis values, it has disappeared.

What is cause this bug?

Comment: 500000 pixels across divided by 5 ticks across = 100000 pixels between each tick. It's a design issue you made, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It is related to ticks,
When the width is get bigger in order to see more values in the axes you need to increase the ticks

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(1555);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ticks are there (all 5).  As you specified, there are only 5 ticks.  On such a large width, it is hard to locate.  Ify ou change .ticks(5) to say .ticks(5000) on the xAxis definition, you would see more ticks.